# Question about how to exit program with exception

Tags: java, exception

Assume that I want to exit a console program if the user entered the char f, and in any time of the program.
The user is supposed to enter some info but I want for each step he entering the input to be able to stop all the operation if he entered "f"? 
How can I do that?
Should it be something like:

```
try
{
 if (userchoice.equals("F"))
  {
    throw new exception e;
  }
}
catch (exception e)
{
  System.exit(1);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: If the exception is not caught it may exit your program anyway. Are you sure this is really needed?

Comment: Can you wait until the user press <ENTER>, or you want to exit exactly on pressing 'f'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the correct syntax:

```
try {
  if (userchoice.equals("F")) {
     throw new Exception();
  }
} catch (Exception e){
  System.exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks but is it right in a matter of programming to exit with the use of exception, or other way? Thanks again

Comment: Silently catching any exception might not be the best approach. ;)

Comment: @Andreas_D : You missed out a " in the equals parameter. Edited on behalf of you. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @GAEBeginner - it works as expected. May not be a usual pattern, exceptions usually signal *exceptional states*. And a valid user entry `F` is more *expected* then *exceptional*. But it works this way.

Comment: Using exceptions for flow control is an abusive use of exceptions.It would be better to throw an `IllegalArgumentException` without handling it or using `System.exit` directly. But throwing exceptions to catch them a few lines later is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can throw the exception, unless it is caught it will cause the current thread to die.

```
if ("f".equalsCaseIgnore(userchoice))
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Option "+userchoice+" not allowed.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

- [`Scanner`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class
- [`System.exit();`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29)

Answer (score 0):

Do the following.

- Read the input from the command line using classes like [`BufferedReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) or [`Scanner`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).
- Check for the character "f" from the i/p'ed string.
- Throw your exception using `throw new MyException();`
- Catch the exception in the catch block and terminate it with `System.exit(1);`

If you require "f" or "F", use `equalsIgnoreCase()` function.

Try something like this,

```
  try{
    if (userchoice.equals("F")) {
         throw new MyException;
       }
    }
 catch (MyException e) {
  System.out.println("MyException caught because i/p character was F" + e);
  System.exit(1);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The input of the char "f" is expected behavior and so throwing an exception may be wrong way.

Encapsulate your input in a method which is responsible to handle the input and decided behavior.

Just call system.exit() here if the user entered "f" or call an exit method that does the work.